# Errors in prepositions of the sentence

Tags: prepositions

I have a grammar assignment and the question is **"Rewrite the sentences below by correcting the errors in the prepositions"** The sentence is **"Everyone was meeting up with me at my house"** I don't see what's wrong in the sentence and I do not know which word is the preposition.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with the sentence, but there are three words in the sentence that could be called prepositions. _With_ and _at_ are always prepositions, but _up_ in _meet up_ can be called a preposition or a particle or an adverb. At least.

Comment: I am sure the answer they are looking for is to drop the *"up with"*. But that only works if you think *"meet up with"* is an ungrammatical synonym for *"meet"* with unnecessary redundant words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the *up*, you are likely to satisfy the expectations of the grammar assignment, but it seems this assignment ignores the fluid reality of English *[idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meet+up)*:

> meet up v.
>
> 1. To come together at a place, especially in order to accomplish something; meet:
>
> *Let's meet up after the meeting and discuss this further.*
>
> 2. *meet up to* To have some required level of quality:
>
> *I think our performance will meet up to your expectations.*
>
> 3. *meet up with* To come together with someone or something, especially in order to
>      accomplish something; meet with someone or something:
>
> *We'll meet up with the others later and decide where to eat dinner.*

You will notice that *meet up* is followed by a different preposition in each of the example sentences. I agree with the flexible analysis of John Lawler's comment, but not everyone appreciates our flexibility. Some see it strictly as two consecutive prepositions: a messy habit in both speech and writing. From *[Common Writing Errors](http://www.upwritepress.com/BlogRetrieve.aspx?BlogID=2395&PostID=72091)*:

> The last nonstandard construction to consider is the double
>   preposition. There are actually two incorrect ways to double your
>   prepositions. The first involves using two consecutive prepositions
>   when only one is necessary. Examples are off of and off to. Instead of
>   saying Pens roll off of the desk, simply say, Pens roll off the desk.
>   And instead of saying I'm flying off to the convention, say, I'm
>   flying to the convention...

That is generally good advice. Why add unnecessary words? Let's return to the three examples sentences and remove the extra "preposition":

> 1. *Let's meet ... after the meeting and discuss this further.*
> 2. *I think our performance will meet ... your expectations.*
> 3. *We'll meet ... the others later and decide where to eat dinner.*

Fewer words actually got the job done quite well.

The problem is that some expressions, like *meet up* and *meet up to*,  have become so common, that people begin to think of them as unique units of meaning: [*fixed expressions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_expression). Notice how the use of *meet up* spikes after 1980 in this [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeet%20up%3B%2Cc0)? If you examine the books that use the expression, it has clearly become an acceptable way to say *meet*, but with a specific subtle twist. If we ignore these subtle changes, we may find ourselves disconnected from the people we want to talk to.

While we are learning, there is an advantage to *drawing inside the lines* our teachers draft for us--even if others consider those lines too restrictive. We are learning an extremely valuable lesson of language: ***to respect the way others see things***. We will have plenty of opportunity to draw outside the lines, because our language is alive and changing with us.

---

idioms.thefreedictionary

www.upwritepress.com

en.wikipedia.or

books.google.com/ngrams

Answer (score 0):

"Meeting with me", is correct. "Meet up", is incorrect but has become so common that no one notices anymore.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer: " Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." :)